# VBA If elseif and list of conditions

Tags: vba, list, if-statement

I have a code for looping through all cells in a range, but I have just found out that the second condition below (`cell.row()<>1`) should actually be changed into something like `cell.row<>1,2,3,4,5` - so a list of exclusions. Is there a quick way of changing this, easier that changing the whole `If-Elseif` into a `Select Case` statement?

```
For Each cell In MyTable
    If cell.Row() = TableFirstRow And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then
        'do stuff
    ElseIf cell.Row() <> 1 And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then
        'do some other stuff
    Elseif...
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a range with all rows to exclude, and use Application.Intersect to check your condition like:

```
Dim RowsToExclude as Range
Set RowsToExclude = Union([1],[2], ...)
...
    ElseIf Application.Intersect(cell, RowsToExclude) Is Nothing And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then
```

or if you rather not use an additional variable:

```
ElseIf Application.Intersect(cell, Union([1],[2],[3])) Is Nothing And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then
```

or even:

```
ElseIf Application.Intersect(cell, [1:6]) Is Nothing And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea for when (re-)scripting it from scratch. Right now I am trying to do minimal changes to a code that has quite some `Elseif`s conditions...

Comment: Well, I really don't see how you could do less changes than that, I just add a variable and modify one line. I've tried to keep it maintainable, that's why I separated the exclusion range, but you can always integrate the Union() inside the Intersect or use a static range definition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like:

```
For Each cell In MyTable
    If cell.Row() = TableFirstRow And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then
        'do stuff
    ElseIf not "|1|2|3|4|5|" like "*|" & cell.Row() & "|*" And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then
        'do some other stuff
    Elseif...
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: I get an compiler error for the `not`; removing it gets rid of the compile error; so I tried reversing the condition into `ElseIf "|5|6|7|8|" Like "*|" & cell.Row() & "|*" And cell.Column() = TableFirstColumn Then`, it runs, but does not do anything (or at least nothing visible)

Comment: NOT was in wrong place... needs to be next to ElseIf

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with collections (which miss the inclusion operator), and strings (with `instr` as operator), I finally resort to ranges. The row numbers to exclude can be specified as a list for ease of use:

```
Sub TestExclusions()
    Dim cell As Range, ExcludedRows As Range
    Dim ExRowNumbers, i
    ExRowNumbers = Array(1, 3, 5, 6, 7)

    ' initialize exclusions
    Set ExcludedRows = Rows(ExRowNumbers(LBound(ExRowNumbers))) ' first exclusion
    For Each i In ExRowNumbers
        Set ExcludedRows = Union(ExcludedRows, Rows(i))
    Next i


    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Not IsIn(cell, ExcludedRows) Then
            ' ...  do something
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Public Function IsIn(rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range) As Boolean
    IsIn = Not (Intersect(rg1, rg2) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Of course one could embed the one-liner directly but it's more flexible (and less dauting) to wrap it into a function.